# Why do some Flask apps have `.db` in each SQLAlchemy statement, while others do not?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I find that some Flask apps use `.db` to begin every SQL query, and in every column and table declaration in their model (see https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database).  It appears the official documentation uses this format.

But other apps, like one I originally started from a tutorial, do not (https://github.com/j10sanders/WinTheMini/blob/master/crossword/database.py)

I assume it has something to do with this difference:
`from app import db` vs `from . import app`, but I don't understand what is really happening.

Comment: Please, post relevant code here, it's hard to keep looking in your linked pages.

Comment: Sure.  This is the version with `.db`: 
`class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
`
This is the version I have, without: 
`class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(128), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(128), unique=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones that use a flask extension called `Flask-SQLAlchemy` for maintaining a global session, connection pool etc use the `db` syntax you talk about.  You can see the API in the docs http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/.